# Object reference not set to an instance of an object [C#]

Tags: c#, linq, row, datarow, mysqldatareader

I am getting the following error:

`Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

I don't know what is the cause of this error and how to solve it, here is my code:

```
while(dr.Read())
    {
     string variant = dr.GetString(0);
     int size = dr.GetInt32(1);
     int quantity = dr.GetInt32(2);

     DataRow x = dt.Rows
                  .Cast<DataRow>()
                  .Where(r => r["variant_name"].Equals(variant) && r["size"].Equals(size))
                  .FirstOrDefault();
                  x["quantity"] = quantity;             

      }
```

I'm getting the error on this line -> `x["quantity"] = quantity;`
I'm wondering why it would give a null value because I checked in my database that it should return exactly one match.

Comment: Pretty straight forward...The error is very descriptive

Comment: `x` is null, so your `Where` clause is not yielding any results.

Answer (score 3):

FirstOrDefault returns null if the element is not found and you try to access this object.

Comment: Sir I already check my database and it should give at least one match.

Comment: Try adding a breakpoint just before x["quantity"] = quantity; and check the value of x. I am pretty sure it is null when you get this error.

Comment: In visual studio, go to the line you want to break at and press F9

Answer (score 2):

On the last line x is  null, fix with

```
if(x != null)
   x["quantity"] = quantity;
```

This  happens if your condition (.Where) doesn't yield a match.
At that point the `FirstOrDefault` return the Default part
and this is a null for a reference object as [explained in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx)

> The default value for reference and nullable types is null.

Comment: I check my database and it should give at least one match.

Comment: Sorry Sir...I don't know what to change in that line of code. What do you think is wrong in that line `.Where`?

Comment: No, I was thinking about a reference problem, but this is not the case. Are you sure that the string in your database field "variant_name" is written in the exact case of your test condition (no spaces or linefeed also)

Comment: If I understand you correctly, Yes I'm pretty sure that it is the same. Actually I've tried to check what is the value of the `variant` by using a messagebox and it returns the same.

Comment: I have no explanation then, if you have a row with the exact variant_name and exact size this code should return a match

Answer (score 0):

```
while(dr.Read())
 {
  string variant = dr.GetString(0);
  int size = dr.GetInt32(1);
  int quantity = dr.GetInt32(2);

  DataRow x = dt.Rows
                .Cast<DataRow>()
                .Where(r => (r["variant_name"].ToString().Equals(variant) && Convert.ToInt32(r["size"]).Equals(size)))
                .FirstOrDefault();

   if (x != null)
   {
       x["quantity"] = quantity;  
   }       
 }
```

Thank you for your answer it helped me a lot. I just changed the line `.Where` a little bit and now it works for me. Thank you again!